# Connecting to AWS Aurora DB running in private subnet from 'outside world'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora, aws-elb

We have an Aurora DB cluster running in a private subnet, and want to allow read only access to clients originating from a fixed set of ips (our company ips). Our requirements are:

- The endpoint for DB read calls should be constant so that various ETL clients trying to read this data do not have to change their scripts repeatedly.
- We do not want to make the DB instances publicly accessible.
- The DB connections should use SSL.

Could someone please direct me with the right steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 things you need to do:

***1. Setting up a OpenVPN Server***

Setup a OpenVPN server that allows clients to 'be inside' the VPC allowing access to any resources inside the VPC. The access can be further restricted by implementing Network ACLs / Security Groups. You can set up a OpenVPN server by following the [tutorial here](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/139855-setting-up-openvpn-server-on-aws-an-overview). After setting up the server, the clients will have to log in to the VPN using the credentials you provide.

***2. Setting up a User on AuroraDB with Read-Only Permissions***

In order for clients to access the AuroraDB cluster from the private subnet (after logging in to VPN of course), you'll need to create a database user with read-only permissions to the DB. If you would like, you can further restrict the user to access only a specific set of tables in your DB.

> Once these two are implemented, your clients will be able to access
>   the database in read only mode from inside the private subnet.